# Properly test queries that are slow on first run

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

How can you test a query that's only slow on first run?¹ Are [`CHECKPOINT` and `DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/382122/can-someone-explain-dbcc-dropcleanbuffers) the right tool? If so, is running this as *sysadmin* all that's needed or there's something else involved?

```
CHECKPOINT;
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS;
GO
```

I'm asking before I can't make the query slow any more, unless I restart the SQL Server instance (which is of course painfully slow).

<sub>(1) Nothing subtle: 35 s to 51 s on first run, around 0.02 s afterwards</sub>

Comment: Just to make sure: you're doing this on a dev box, right? Those aren't the kind of commands you want to be running in prod to troubleshoot slow queries, because they'll likely make other stuff slow.

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik Correct. I want to try different approaches (indexes, query rewrites...) and find out whether they work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restarting Sql Server blows away the plan cache so the first time the query is executed, a new execution plan has to be built.  Check out [Eight Different Ways to Clear the SQL Server Plan Cache](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/glenn/eight-different-ways-to-clear-the-sql-server-plan-cache/).

Alternatively, you could try altering the text of your query by adding (or removing) some extra spaces or blank lines which should force a new plan to be built.

However, I'd be quite surprised if it took 35 to 51 seconds to build a new plan.

You can verify whether building a new execution plan is part of your extended execution time by issuing `set statistics time on` in a query session before you execute your query against an empty plan cache (or where you've made a slight change to the query text such that a new execution plan is required).  In the SSMS messages window, look for something like this:

```
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 1 ms.
```

Additionally, have a look at [Why is My Query Faster the Second Time it Runs?](https://littlekendra.com/2016/11/25/why-is-my-query-faster-the-second-time-it-runs-dear-sql-dba-episode-23/)

Comment: I have seen excessively slow compile times in some cases with the new CE and a query with many joins but that doesn't apply to SQL 2008R2.

Comment: May not actually be compile-time but buffering the tables to memory.

Comment: The initial slowdown becomes 100% reproducible if I add `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE` to the cocktail. I also get `SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 37671 ms, elapsed time = 37920 ms.` (otherwise, that info doesn't show up for the first time).

Comment: @DanGuzman Funny, I have that problem as well (tons of joins here) with newer versions. Is there a "simple" fix apart from setting database compatibility to `SQL Server 2008 (100)`? I have the 43-page *Optimizing Your Query Plans with the SQL Server 2014 Cardinality Estimator* document here but I can't grasp any meaning from it.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, SQL 2016 introduces `ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION` so you can set the CE independently of the database compatibility level and without trace flags. A lot of joins suggests a complex query, not necessarily a CE bug. A specific repro script with DDL and query will help us help you.

Comment: @DanGuzman It's okay, it'd be rather off-topic in this question. (BTW, complex query or not, I remember I was getting awful execution times with **empty tables**, until I found the compatibility level workaround.)